# Install any apk from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to install apk from within Eclipse IDE by right-clicking on apk file (that may be in any project, no need for ADT).

The system command to execute is `adb install app-name.apk`

How to archive that in Eclipse IDE ?

To run some tool Eclipse External tool may be used (that I don't know well),
but that will not appear in context menu for right-button mouse click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Eclipse lets you right-click any file, and use `Open With -> Other` , where you can choose any external program or script.  On Windows, I created a simple batch script with below line (you should be able to do something similar on other platforms)

  `adb install -r %1`

  and in eclipse, i right-click an apk file, and choose `Open With -> Other -> above batch script` , Eclipse then successfully installed the APK.
- Another option: you can create Eclipse plugin, using its Commands interface. This lets you add a context-menu/right-click action. You can execute your adb command from there. Creating this plugin can be easy, [please take a look at this code snippet for a sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856825/trouble-deciding-how-to-add-popup-menu-to-eclipse-plugin-using-either-action-obj/13877086#13877086).

Ideally you would want to use the `-r` option  so it re-installs if apk already present on device : `adb install -r app-name.apk`.

Comment: creating plugin is an option to use when Eclipse IDE cannot help solving problem with existing tools. Also this example is not enough even when knowing how to start new plugin project.